# I suspect Docker port mapping suffers with /metadata's mixture of relative|absolute URLs

Tags: c#, mono, servicestack

I have a copy of the very simple C#, self-hosted ServiceStack proof-of-concept running on Mono under Docker. Let's assume I'm surfacing the container as mydomain.com on port 80.

The metadata page combines (I think) relative (e.g. Service Types --> ?xsd=1) and absolute (e.g. Program.Hello JSON --> http://mydomain:8080/json/metadata?op=Program.Hello) links.

The relative links map across just fine. The absolutes, not so much.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting

The relevant code is here:

```
var listeningOn = args.Length == 0 ? "http://*:8080/" : args[0];
(new AppHost()).Init().Start(listeningOn);
```

Am I correct that ServiceStack is explicitly absolute referencing the types (XML,JSON) etc. and that this is the cause of the problem?

Or, is this just my naivete in the use of the framework and you can tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?